# Can't figure out how to implement fourier series in python

Tags: python, math

I have resently stumbled uppon this Video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r6sGWTCMz2k by 3Blue1Brown explaining what a fourier series is.
I was amazed by this mathematical pattern which seems like sorcery and wanted to implement it for myself. So, a lot of investigation later and I think I have gotten the basic hang of it, however my code does not yet work.
I am using the discrete Fourier Transform to compute the phase and radius of epicycles, which each rotate with a certain frequency in an arbitrary range, to trace out a line which passes through a bunch of given sample points.
I'm using the module pygame to visualize what i am doing and the module cmath for the exp operation.

```
import pygame as pg
import cmath

# my implementation of the fast fourier transform
def fft(samples, k): # takes in the samplepoints and a frequency
    N = len(samples)

    # summing all the ft's for the sample points up and normalizing them
    sum_ = 0
    for n in range(0, N):
        sum_ += samples[n] * cmath.exp(-2 * cmath.pi * 1j * k * n / N)
    return sum_

def main():
    pg.init()
    RES = WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1000, 600
    screen = pg.display.set_mode(RES)
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    font = pg.font.Font('assets/Fonts/Raleway/Raleway-Light.ttf', 16)

    # sample points I want to use (a square):
    samplepoints = [[-1, -1], [1, -1], [1, 1], [-1, 1]]

    # creating more sample points through interpolation for better aproximation of the path
    samplepoints_len = len(samplepoints)
    new_samplepoints = []
    samples = 100 # total number of samples I want
    for i in range(samples):
        n_ = i / samples * samplepoints_len
        t = n_ % 1
        index = int(n_)
        p = (
                samplepoints[index][0] + (samplepoints[(index + 1) % samplepoints_len][0] - samplepoints[index][0]) * t, # interpolate between the current and the next sample point
                samplepoints[index][1] + (samplepoints[(index + 1) % samplepoints_len][1] - samplepoints[index][1]) * t  # interpolate between the current and the next sample point
            )
        new_samplepoints.append(p)
    samplepoints = new_samplepoints

    # create a complex set of sample points
    complex_samplepoints = [complex(s[0], s[1]) for s in samplepoints]

    # compute the coefficients for the different frequency epicycles
    coeffs = [fft(complex_samplepoints, k) for k in range(-int(samples / 2), int(samples) + 1)]

    # t = time
    # s = scalar for drawing purposes
    # path = the path that will be traced out by the epicycles
    t = 0
    s = 100
    path = []
    
    while True:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                pg.quit()
                quit()

        # increment time
        t += 0.5

        screen.fill('black')
        surf = font.render('t: ' + str(round(t, 4)), True, (255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(surf, (20, 20))

        # computing the fourier series at point t in time
        n = samples
        ftx = 0 # fourier transform x
        fty = 0 # fourier transform y
        for i in range(-int(samples / 2), int(samples / 2) + 1): # looping through all the different frequencys
            e = coeffs[i] * cmath.exp(-2 * cmath.pi * 1j * t / n) # computing the current epicycle position
            
            ftx += e.real # incrementing the x value, essentialy adding up the epicycles
            fty += e.imag # incrementing the y value, essentialy adding up the epicycles
        
        ftx /= n # normalizing the computed values
        fty /= n # normalizing the computed values

        path.append((ftx * s + WIDTH / 2, fty * s + HEIGHT / 2)) # add last epicycles position to the path

        pg.draw.lines(screen, (80, 80, 80), False, [(p[0] * s + WIDTH / 2, p[1] * s + HEIGHT / 2) for p in samplepoints], 1) # drawing the sample points

        # draw the path on screen
        if len(path) > 1:
            pg.draw.lines(screen, 'white', False, path, 1)
        
        pg.draw.circle(screen, (255, 128, 128), (ftx * s + WIDTH / 2, fty * s + HEIGHT / 2), 5) # drawing the last epicycle position

        pg.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is what I've got so far:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdPgf.gif

Can anyone explain what is wrong with my code?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: My expected output for the coefficients would be a set of complex numbers that discribe the behaviour of epicycles spinning around each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I solved it

Turns out the core of the Problem was just how I calculated the `coeffs` and that I used a wrong exponent for the section in the main loop where the current point for the path gets computed.

I used to compute the `coeffs` over the interval from `-int(samples / 2)` to `int(samples / 2) + 1`. The fixed version computes them from `0` to `samples`:

```
coeffs = [fft(complex_samplepoints, k) for k in range(0, samples)]
```

In the section of the code were I would calculate the current point in time I used the wrong exponent `cmath.exp(-2 * cmath.pi * 1j * t / n)`.
The right exponent looks like this:

```
cmath.exp(-1j * 2 * cmath.pi * k * t) * coeffs[k] / samples
```

Hope that helps somebody.

I also build a little GitHub Repo with a programm that enables you to play arround with the algorithm:

https://github.com/m-J-K-b/FourierSeriesImplementation